# How can I access one attached filter from another in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filter

I have set up a file to hold filters attached to my Vue object, this is `required` into my App.js.  However I have a filter that would ideally use another filter:

```
Vue.filter('formatDateTime', value => {
    if (value)  return moment(String(value)).format('DD-MMM-YY hh:mm')
});
Vue.filter('getActivity', value =>
    (!value.lastvisited)
        ? 'Not visited yet' 
        : 'Last logged in ' + Vue.$options.filters.formatDateTime(value.lastvisited)
)
```

but it can't reference the global Vue object, is there a way around this?
I can of course repeat the date formatting code, but I would prefer not to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one option is to seperate definition and global registration

(plus its now usable/importable in non-vue context)

```
// ie. in filters.js
export const formatDateTime = value => value 
  ? moment(String(value)).format('DD-MMM-YY hh:mm') 
  : null

export const getActivity = value => !value.lastvisited
  ? 'Not visited yet' 
  : 'Last logged in ' + formatDateTime(value.lastvisited)

// ie. in in a filter-global-registration.js
import { getActivity, formatDateTime } from 'filters.js'

Vue.filter('formatDateTime', formatDateTime);
Vue.filter('getActivity', getActivity)
```

Comment: Just had to tediously retype all my filters to add this extra layer of abstraction, but I do agree it is a nice way of structuring this.  And it works! which is a bonus.

Comment: This solution works in most cases, but when you still need your Vue object inside a filter (for instance a translation plugin or whatever you might need) you will have to get a reference to it somehow.

Comment: @Flame, correct but I would argue that as soon as something needs `this`, it is either `computed` or `methods` not (as I see it) a side-effect-free filter. i.e: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MLxbEW

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is create a global reference to your main Vue object, like:

```
// Create a filter which calls another filter.
Vue.filter('myFilter', () => {
    window.Vue.$options.filters.myOtherFilter(...);
});

// Initialize the main Vue object.
window.Vue = new Vue({

});
```

Then, you should be able to access your filters using `window.Vue.$options.filters.myOtherFilter()` inside of your filter functions.

It might not be ideal but it has helped me out on several occasions where you have to define plugins/services/components that dont give you the current Vue instance it uses.

Comment: That is exactly how I have done it, it fails with `window.Vue` also, however I have done these the opposite way round, initialized the main Vue object before defining the filters, not sure if that matters in javascript world?

Comment: I've explicitly tested it now, it works. You want to create the filters before you create the `new Vue({})` instance. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html it states "...or define a filter globally before creating the Vue instance"

Comment: That's interesting, +1 for referencing the documentation, I have taken the approach suggested by @birdspider now because it also adds some good code structure to the solution